# Adding a video filter to direct show project

Tags: c++, video, directshow

I have a c++ project that use DirectShow successfully.
But it can open any media files (like mpeg2 or some Avi).

How can I develop my project to increase supported formats?

Answer (score 0):

DirectShow itself if a framework which is not constrained to specific formats. For a particular format or encoding to be supported, respective software components (filters) need to be installed and registered and they will participate in media pipelines responsible for loading, decoding, encoding and saving specific additional formats of interest.